# Java UDF processing array column

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing a java udf to process a array type column.

The purpose is to process an array of string to select the one with the shortest length

```
sqlContext.udf().register("NAME_SELECTOR", (UDF1<List<String>, String>) brandNames -> {
                          brandNames.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
                          return brandNames.get(0);},DataTypes.StringType);
```

The error was related to the input type of the UDF function. I know that in scala I need to use `Seq[String]` as the input type, how about in Java?

Here is the error message:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

Use **`scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray`** and convert it to the java list using `JavaConverters` then sort it using comparator and fetch the first shortest string-

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql("select array('abc', 'ab', 'a') arr");
        df.printSchema();
        df.show(false);
        /**
         * root
         *  |-- arr: array (nullable = false)
         *  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
         *
         * +------------+
         * |arr         |
         * +------------+
         * |[abc, ab, a]|
         * +------------+
         */

        // scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
        UserDefinedFunction shortestStringUdf = udf((WrappedArray<String> arr)  -> {
                    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(JavaConverters
                            .asJavaCollectionConverter(arr)
                            .asJavaCollection());
                    strings.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
                    return strings.get(0);
                }
                , DataTypes.StringType);
        spark.udf().register("shortestString", shortestStringUdf);

        df.withColumn("a", expr("shortestString(arr)"))
        .show(false);
        /**
         * +------------+---+
         * |arr         |a  |
         * +------------+---+
         * |[abc, ab, a]|a  |
         * +------------+---+
         */
```

If you are on **`spark>=2.4`** use higher order functions to achieve same result **`without udf`** as below-

```java
 // spark>=2.4
        df.withColumn("arr_length", expr("TRANSFORM(arr, x -> length(x))"))
                .withColumn("a", expr("array_sort(arrays_zip(arr_length, arr))[0].arr"))
                .show(false);
        /**
         * +------------+----------+---+
         * |arr         |arr_length|a  |
         * +------------+----------+---+
         * |[abc, ab, a]|[3, 2, 1] |a  |
         * +------------+----------+---+
         */
```

Comment: Please feel free to upvote + accept if it helps- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/767994